# Simple elaboration on Joint Models' linear equations/trajectory functions

Tags: time-series, survival, hazard, time-varying-covariate

I have been struggling with grasping the intuition behind joint models, and I hope someone can elucidate a particular aspect of theirs. Joint models, first of all, are essentially combinations of linear model + survival model, in order to be able to estimate *"the time left"* to an *"event"*, at any arbitrary point within a time series. A good intuitive description is found [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/an-introduction-to-joint-modeling-in-r/).

The purpose of joint models is clear, as the above link demonstrates. A doctor might want to know, at any moment, how much longer (based on a patient's treatment and his/her biomarker history/time series data) they can be expected to survive.

However, following this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4503792/pdf/zlj2796.pdf), I would extremely appreciate help understanding the trajectory function mentioned on page 2.

To make sure I am on the right track, I created some [dummy data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMIoN.jpg) of 3 patients: the first 2 receive a treatment and survive longer (later `Time-of-event`), while the last does not, and, unfortunately, dies earlier. There also exists an arbitrary `Bio-marker` that is being measured (like white blood cell count).

On the same page, the linear model aspect of joint models is presented,

$$Y_{ij} = X_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij}\, ,$$

where $Y_{ij}$ is an "observed outcome" (so I assume it is some `Bio-marker`), and $X_{ij}$ is some "trajectory function" that stands for the following:

$$X_{ij} = \theta_{0i} + \theta_{1i} * t_{ij} + \gamma Z_i\, .$$

$Z_i$ is the presence (or not) of the treatment (`1` or `0`). However, the rest of the equation makes no sense to me. I agree that the `Bio-marker` should be affected by the presence of the treatment, but why would one assume that the `Bio-marker` grows with time so naively, in the first place? Wouldn't an ARIMA model (or any more robust time-series approach) be more believable for $X_{ij}$?

If anyone could elaborate on the trajectory function (why it is assumed to be this way, what other structures could be used instead, etc), I would extremely appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of points:

- Joint models combine a linear *mixed* model (not a simple linear model) with a survival (typically a relative risk) model. Namely, in the specification of the model for $Y_i$, the coefficients $\theta_{i0}$ and $\theta_{i1}$ are random effects that are different from subject to subject. These specification translates to accounting for the correlations in the repeated measurements of the biomarker values of each subject.
- The specification presented in this paper is just one/simple formulation of the linear mixed model part of the joint model. Depending on the features of your data (i.e., how the shapes of the subject-specific biomarker profiles look like, and how strong the correlations are in the repeated measurements of each subject), you could fit more elaborate models that postulate that the biomarker has a nonlinear evolution over time. This can be done by including polynomials or splines in the specification of the fixed- and random-effects parts of the model.
- You can find more detailed info on joint models in my course notes: http://www.drizopoulos.com/ -> Teaching.

Comment: Thank you for taking an interest in my question, and for linking your own notes on the subject (I have been going over them quite fervently now). Going through them, a few questions have arisen that, I think express more specific aspects of my general confusion regarding joint models, and which I hope you can answer. They are all based on your notes here: http://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/EMC/ESP72.pdf

Comment: 1) On pg. 85, after having stated that $y_i$ stands for longitudinal markers (like white blood cell count, or sex), and $\beta_i$ and $b_i$ are the fixed and random effects, respectively, what then do $x_i$ and$z_i$ stand for? They seem to represent some real data, but $y_i$ is already stated to represent the longitudinal data. I grasp the linear mixed-effects aspect of the model, but not this part.

Comment: 2) On pg. 87, you state that "random effects explain all [the] interdependencies [for joint models]."  I am having a severely difficult time conceptualizing this. Could you give more elaboration on what this means, or describe a possible alternate interdependency arrangement within Joint Models, with different strength and weaknesses?

Comment: Regarding (1), $y_i$ is indeed a longitudinally measured biomarker (most often sex cannot be consider such a biomarker because it does not change over time). For this marker you postulate a mixed model, which has a fixed-effects part described by $x_i$ and $\beta$ and random-effects part by $z_i$ and $b_i$. The former describes the average of $y_i$ over time and the latter the correlations in the repeated measurements of the biomarker of each subject over time. Check Chapter 2 in the course notes and/or my course notes for my Repeated Measurements course.

Comment: Regarding (2) the random effects are *unobserved* variables that explain why the observed outcomes, namely the longitudinal outcome and the time-to-event are associated. One way to think of it is that the random effects represent a summary of all the environmental, genetic and other factors that you have not observed in your study that explain why a particular subject has, say high levels in the biomarker that increase over time, which in turn leads to a higher risk (hazard) of having the event.

Comment: So, in your repeated measurements course (http://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/EMC/CE08.pdf), on pg.s 43-45, 153, it seems that the design matrices, $x_i$ and $z_i$, do stand for some variables. So what is the general rule for which variables stand for them, if our **important** variables (like white blood cell count), are taken by all of the $y$'s?

Comment: Your explanation for (2) at least gives me comfort, in that you made the random effects sound like they are rigorous in their ability to capture different interdependencies.

However, my knowledge of *random effects* comes from a Bayesian standpoint, where they are called *hierarchical models*, and maybe thinking about it that way is confusing me. The fact that each *sub-group* coefficient is drawn from a general population prior, does not explain to me how weird interdependencies could be captured.

Comment: Specifically, my main reference is this https://twiecki.io/blog/2017/02/08/bayesian-hierchical-non-centered/ .
If you could help me understand more how random effects capture interdependencies, I am more than willing to award bounty (though I know you do not need it).

Comment: (a quick example, on pg. 157 of your repeated measurements course, https://imgur.com/h9UOu6s, you ***only make time a random effect***, and I am sure there is a lot you could say regarding that)

Comment: The consideration in Bayesian hierarchical models can be along the same lines. Namely, why do you want to assume that the coefficients in specific sub-groups are different? What makes them being different? Again you could say/assume that a set of unobserved factors makes the outcome of interest to behave differently in one sub-group than in another, which translates to having different coefficients.